# Twilio send SMS to multiple users from website

Tags: php, sms, twilio, twilio-php

I am making a PHP website I am trying to send a message using Twilio whenever the user enters the telephone number in the website. Currently it only sends a message to the number I wrote in my code. How can I make it send to the entered number?

```
<?php
 require('Twilio.php');
// ==== Control Vars =======
$strFromNumber = "";
$strToNumber = "";
$strMsg = "Hey!! ";  
$aryResponse = array();

    // set our AccountSid and AuthToken - from www.twilio.com/user/account
    $AccountSid = "";
    $AuthToken = "";


    // ini a new Twilio Rest Client
    $objConnection = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);


    // Send a new outgoinging SMS by POSTing to the SMS resource

    $bSuccess = $objConnection->account->sms_messages->create(

        $strFromNumber,     // number we are sending from 
        $strToNumber,           // number we are sending to
        $strMsg         // the sms body
    );



    $aryResponse["SentMsg"] = $strMsg;
    $aryResponse["Success"] = true;

    echo json_encode($aryResponse);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `$strToNumber` to what ever number the person types in. You can get this on a [form submission](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp).

If you use a post request, you can send the user to a php page that gets the number:

Example form:

```
<form action="[path to your php file].php" method="post">
    Phone Number: <input type="tel" name="phone"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In [path to your php file].php, put the code you had above, and set `$strToNumber` to `$_POST["number"]`:

```
$strToNumber = $_POST["number"];
```

Twilio also charges money when you send a message, and if you are on a trail account, you might not be able to send a message.

Comment: $strToNumber = "$_POST["cellphone"];"; like this?

Comment: @AadeshShah I don't do php, but `$strToNumber = $_POST["number"];` should work. There is no need to use quotes to surround code.

Comment: @AadeshShah Glad to help! Press that check mark to show others that this answer solved your question.